# Python Programming approach - data manipulation in excel

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I'm using the python packages xlrd and xlwt to read and write from excel spreadsheets using python. I can't figure out how to write the code to solve my problem though.

So my data consists of a column of state abbreviations and a column of numbers, 1 through 7. There are about 200-300 entries per state, and i want to figure out how many ones, twos, threes, and so on exist for each state. I'm struggling with what method I'd use to figure this out.

normally i would post the code i already have but i don't even know where to begin.

Comment: This obviously divides into three parts: (1) Read the data from the Excel file into some Python structure like a list of lists. (2) Process the data the same way you would if it came from a CSV file or a bunch of literals. (3) Output whatever you want to output. Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: My only piece of advice would be to use `pywin32` and drive Excel through COM. And just do it as you would do it by hand but with Python.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare a dictionary to store the results.
2. Get the numbers of line with data you have using xlrd, then iterate over each of them.
3. For each state code, if it's not `in` the dict, you create it also as a dict.
4. Then you check if the entry you read on the second column exists within the state key on your results dict.

   4.1 If it does not, you'll create it also as a dict, and add the number found on the second column as a key to this dict, with a value of one.

   4.2 If it does, just increment the value for that key (+1).

Once it has finished looping, your result dict will have the count for each individual entry on each individual state.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you already know how to do to the easy part of this and read a spreadsheet into Python as a list of lists. So, you've got something like this:

```
data = [['CA', 1],
        ['AZ', 2],
        ['NM', 3],
        ['CA', 2]]
```

Now, what you want for each state, for each number, a count of the number of times that number appears. So:

```
counts = {}
for state, number in data:
    counts.setdefault(state, collections.Counter())[number] += 1
```

Comment: This is perfect, I was completely unaware of the Counter object or of collections.Counter() for that matter. I am, however, getting this error, after adding "import collections" and "from collections import Counter":  TypeError: unhashable type: 'Counter'
and my google search was unsuccessful...

Comment: @aloe-sarah: Sorry, you need to pass the key and the value to `setdefault`, and I left the key out. Try it now.